# How to change Appstore language

Tags: iphone

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 7 and, even if the country and billing info is for Romania, on the phone AppStore and iTunes Store are in german, only a few buttons are in Romanian. I would like them to be in Romanian or english, what can I do? I read online about this issue but nothing works. The phone is in sync with computer.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the following?

1. Go to `Settings`.
2. Tab `iTunes & App Store`.
3. Tab your `Apple ID` and then `Sign Out`.
4. Now `Sign In` and choose `Create New Apple ID` (you won't complete this, don't worry).
5. You'll be asked to choose your store (country/region), choose the country which has the language you want the AppStore to be in (Romania or United States in your case).
6. Click `Next` and then `Agree`.
7. Fill in the information until you're asked to insert your credit card info.
8. When you reach the credit card info, click `Cancel` and exit the `Create New Apple ID` section.
9. Go back to `Settings` and sign in with your actual Apple ID.
10. Open the App Store and everything should be in the language you picked.

### Links

I found [this tutorial](http://www.dearsillyblog.com/2012/04/how-to-fully-change-appstore-language.html), which explains the steps I have listed above.

Answer (score 2):

1. go to settings
2. tab apple store
3. if you already logged in, press your account
4. press see your apple id
5. go to languages
6. select the language you want it to be
7. press cancel
8. go back to your app store and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. go to settings
2. sign out from your account
3. sign in again
4. go back to App Store and it should work.